# python traceback local variables

Tags: python, exception

I am processing 11k documents with a script. When I hit an uncaught exception, the default traceback gives me the line in my script, but not which one of the 11k documents caused the error. I looked at and tried https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/traceback.html but that is just giving me new errors, so clearly I don't know how to make it work. I was trying to use 'capture_locals=True', in the hope that this will tell me which document to look at. What is the right way to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you opening your documents? How are you reading those documents? Please provide at least some code, we need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If your script is simple (`open`, minimal exception handling) why not just keep the file name in a variable, and putting the code line in question into a `try` statement followed by outputting the file name in the `except` block.

Comment: @Chillie 1) I knew about this rule, but I assumed (erroneously, apparently) that this was simple enough that code was not needed. 2) You are absolutely right. That is the simple obvious solution that simply didn't occur to me because I was so focused on it coming from the system instead of me. If you want to make it an answer I will accept and give you the points. Thanks.